# static code analysis: method argument is the same constant on all invocations

Tags: java, methods, static-code-analysis

Is there a freely available static code analysis tool for Java, which can detect that I use the **same constant value as method argument on *all* calls to a method**, so I can remove the argument and use a constant value inside the method body? E.g. in

```
class A {
    void methodA {
        someMethod("first", 42);
    }
}

class B {
    void methodB {
        someMethod("second", 42);
    }
    void methodC {
        someMethod("third", 42);
    }
}
```

I want to have the second argument of someMethod to be reported (given that these 3 calls are *all* calls to that method in my project).

I found no such thing in the Eclipse compiler warnings, Findbugs, CodePro Analytix or UCDetector, but I may have missed the corresponding setting.

EDIT: Just to make sure: I'm not asking for how to remove the constant value by refactorings. I'm asking for how to detect this situation, given that those 3 method invocations might be spread over some thousand source files.

Comment: CheckStyle can find your constants too

Comment: checktyle or intellij inspections ?

Comment: It is unlikely to have such a tool.   Existing tools does not remember what data caused particular line to execute.

Comment: Checkstyle + Eclipse refactoring

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can try to use Sonar:
http://www.sonarsource.org/